# Where can I find a Slavita print Gemara online?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara

Before the Vilna Shas print, there was the Slavita print (as well as others). There are many questions about this Vilna print (from which most Gemaras nowadays are reprints). I'm interested in seeing the differences between the prints (and I'd rather see a print as close as possible to the Romm brothers).

Is it available online?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50468/759